# API Validation Before Proceeding

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I'm working with Instagram's api, and I must validate a profile before form is submitted:

```
<button type="button" id="clickMe">Run It!</button>
  <div id="data">
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#clickMe').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         method: 'get',
         url: 'php-script.php',
         data: {
            'username': '217380759',
            'ajax': true
         },
         success: function(data) {
            $('#data').text(data);
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

php-script.php:

```
$access_token = "...";
$username = "...";
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $username . '?access_token=' . $access_token;
$api_response = file_get_contents($url);
$record = json_decode($api_response);
$code = $record->meta->code;

if($code == 200) {
   //user is valid, continue to next page
} else {
   echo "invalid";
}
```

Any suggestions on verifying Instagram user, allowing user to continue without hitting submit again?

Comment: What is the problem? With this code you obtain correct response? If it is, you can directly retrieve another command, I think. Like `/users/user-id/media/` or whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this code :

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data != 'invalid') {
      location.href = "YOUR NEXT PAGE URL";
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining in more detail? So far I tried it, nothing happened. The reason maybe because it doesn't know what 'invalid' is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry but not getting your point. They means what are you talking about

Comment: I apologize. What I mean to say is, 'invalid' is a php variable, how can it be sad in javascript?

Comment: No it's not a php variable. it's just a string which you have returned in your PHP file.So this can be easily access with `data` variable in JS. And please put `exit();` at the end of your PHP file.

Comment: I understand now, I just tried it out and it's working. Thank you!